# How to use JSON-RPC (web service) in windows phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json-rpc, jayrock

I want to know how to use a Json web service in windows phone application. I am aware that Jayrock has to be used, but I would like some examples. I want to call some methods in the webservice which is given to me in the form of http://"something"/service.json"
Please help.

Comment: Why does Jayrock have to be used?

Comment: I guess for the .NET implementation of Json and JSON-RPC..

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this..

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Consume-JSON-with-Windows-Phone-a-seamless-solution.aspx

But my service was much simpler and did not need all the wcf stack, so I instead hosted it as an asp .net mvc page and render the page in json, instead of html.

You can then use json serializer to parse the data in C#

Comment: for the info, I have not hosted this service. It is a web service that I want to use. I only know the methods, return types and parameters.